Composition of a bounded operator and an unbounded closed operator
Let $T: \mathcal{D}(T) \to H$ be a densely defined and closed unbounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and let $P: H \to H$ be a non-trivial projection operator, particularly bounded and self-adjoint and closed on $H$.
How can I show that the operator  $PT: \mathcal{D}(PT) \to H$ with $\mathcal{D}(PT) = \mathcal{D}(T)$ is a closed operator?
My idea:
To show that the operator $ PT: \mathcal{D}(PT) \to H $ is closed, we need to show that if a sequence $ \{x_n\} \subset \mathcal{D}(T) $ converges to some $ x \in H $ and $ PTx_n $ converges to some $ y \in H $, then $ x \in \mathcal{D}(T) $ and $ PTx = y $.
Suppose $ \{x_n\} \subset \mathcal{D}(T) $ is a sequence such that
$$
   x_n \to x \quad \text{in } H \quad \text{and} \quad PTx_n \to y \quad \text{in } H.
  $$
Since $ T $ is a closed operator and $ \{x_n\} $ converges to $ x $, we need to show that $ T x_n $ converges to some $ z \in H $. By the closedness of $ T $,
$$
   x \in \mathcal{D}(T) \quad \text{and} \quad T x_n \to T x \quad \text{in } H.
   $$
We have $ PT x_n \to y $. Since $ P $ is a bounded operator, we can interchange the limit and the bounded operator:
$$
   P T x_n \to P T x \quad \text{in } H.
   $$
Therefore, we have:
$$
   P T x = y.
   $$
Since $ x \in \mathcal{D}(T) $ and $ PT x = y $, we conclude that $ x \in \mathcal{D}(PT) $ and $ PT x = y $.
Is that correct?

No, this is not correct. The error is in the following step:

Since $T$ is a closed operator and $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$, we need to show that $Tx_n$ converges to some $z \in H$. By the closedness of $T$,
$$x \in \mathcal{D}(T) \quad \text{and} \quad Tx_n \to Tx \quad \text{in } H.$$

For this to work, you’re implicitly assuming $Tx_n$ converges in the first place, which may not be the case.
Indeed, the result is simply false. Say, $H = l^2$, $T$ be the diagonal operator $Te_n = ne_n$, and $P$ be the projection onto $\text{span}\{e_1\}$. Then $PT$ is simply $P$ restricted to $\mathcal{D}(T) \neq H$, so it is not closed. (Though, of course, it is closable.)

One can make $PT$ not even closable. Say, $H = l^2$, $T$ be the diagonal operator $Te_n = 2^ne_n$, and $P$ be the projection onto $\text{span}\{\sum_n 2^{-n/2}e_n\}$. Then $2^{-k/2}e_k \to 0$, but $PT(2^{-k/2}e_k) = \sum_n 2^{-n/2}e_n \not\to 0$.

I see, thanks! So the statement does not hold even with "$PT$ closable....."
Are there any further assumptions I could use to get $PT$ closed?

@kumquat Generally speaking, composing an unbounded operator with a bounded operator to the left is not a good idea. But you can get closability at least in some very specific case, say $T$ is diagonal and $P$ is diagonal (w.r.t. the same ONB) (or, more generally, $P$ can be block diagonal with each block of finite size, w.r.t. that ONB). This won’t necessarily get you a closed operator (with the first example I provided in the answer a counterexample to this), but you do get closability. Another case would be if $T$ is self-adjoint and $P$ is a spectral projection of $T$.

@kumquat If you know about von Neumann algebras, then there is a sort of generalization of both of the above two cases. Namely, if you have a finite vNa s.t. $T$ is affiliated to it and $P$ is in it, then $PT$ is closable (and in fact affiliated to the same finite vNa).

Unfortunately not, but thanks for the cue! On the other hand the construction $TP$ should give me a closed operator at least in the case that $T$ is self-adjoint or skew-adjoint, since the adjoint of $PT$ is well-defined? But than I would stick with the problem that $TP$ is not necessarily densely defined....

@kumquat $TP$ is always closed, as long as $T$ is closed and $P$ is bounded, no additional assumptions needed. (The proof is just the proof in your question, only this time because $P$ is bounded, you do get $Px_n \to Px$.) But you’re right in saying it may not be densely defined. Adding additional assumptions on $T$ wouldn’t help, since as long as $\mathcal{D}(T) \neq H$, you can choose $z \in H \setminus \mathcal{D}(T)$ and let $P$ be the projection onto the span of $z$. Then $\mathcal{D}(TP) = {0}$.
